# Firebase Realtime Database equalTo query for child in increasing keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from database. But after i changed my code for
performance issues on my react-native project, i couldn't find the query for my desire.
The deal is i have this type data structure. it goes under /root/news/0/coin_name. 0 key is
increasing like 1,2,3...n for each of my data. for better understanding:

```js
cnh
I
I
--coins
|
|
--news|
      |
      |--0|
          --coin_name='algorand'
          ...
      |--1|
          ...
```

I want to fetch datas where coin_name equals to such as 'algorand'. I tried some queries but none of them worked. I'd be appreciated if you help me.

i tried:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
        const fbdb = async () =>{
            await database()
      .ref(newsKey)
      .orderByChild('year')
      .equalTo('2021')
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const formattedResponse=formatMarketData(data,show);
        return setNews(formattedResponse)
      });
      };
    
        fbdb();
       
    },[show,year]);
```

**EDIT** Lastly i pushed the datas from my excel file to realtime database, the problem with string datas solved, for the year equalto query i should have parse it to int first, after parsing the year value to integer that problem solved too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
await database()
  .ref('news')
  .orderByChild('coin_name')
  .equalTo('algorand')
```

Note though that these numeric, sequential keys are typically an anti-pattern in Firebase. To learn why, and a more idiomatic structure with push keys, read [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

A working example of this: https://jsbin.com/focaveq/3/edit?js,console

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working. I'm writing the datas by hand from excel, after parsing it into json firebase assigns numeric sequential keys by itself. I'll try to write a push script from excel to firebase in python to assign random string keys to datas, maybe after that this query might work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you script it, you can also prefix the numbers with a string - so like `key0`, `key1`. But that's separate from how to get the query to work, which is what you were asking about. Did you try the code from my answer? Did it work? If not, what happened?

Comment: I did tried your code, without .once('value') query, i couldn't catch the snapshot with .then so i added it and the query returns empty result. With useEffect(()=>{
        const fbdb = async () =>{
            await database()
      .ref(newsKey)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        const formattedResponse=formatMarketData(data,show);
        return setNews(formattedResponse)
      });
      };
    
        fbdb();
       
    },[show,year]); that query i can fetch all data.

Comment: with orderbychildname queries doesn't work at all. I've got another datas in my coins row and when i tried .ref("/coins/coinX").orderByChild('year').equalTo('2021').once('value')... works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  "coins" : [ {
    
  } ],
  "news" : [ {
    "coin_name" : "algorand",
    "event_date" : "2019-06-24",
    "exchange" : "crypto.com",
    "month" : "6",
    "year" : "2019"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "algorand",
    "event_date" : "2021-01-06",
    "exchange" : "bitmart",
    "month" : "1",
    "year" : "2021"
  },  {
    "coin_name" : "litecoin",
    "event_date" : "2020-12-25",
    "exchange" : "binance qtly",
    "month" : "12",
    "year" : "2020"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "litecoin",
    "event_date" : "2021-01-04",
    "exchange" : "coinflex",
    "month" : "1",
    "year" : "2021"
  }, 
     {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2020-06-20",
    "exchange" : "resfinex",
    "month" : "6",
    "year" : "2020"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2020-07-07",
    "exchange" : "all",
    "month" : "7",
    "year" : "2020"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2020-07-10",
    "exchange" : "phemex",
    "month" : "7",
    "year" : "2020"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2021-04-21",
    "exchange" : "all",
    "month" : "4",
    "year" : "2021"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2021-05-19",
    "exchange" : "phemex",
    "month" : "5",
    "year" : "2021"
  }, {
    "coin_name" : "tron",
    "event_date" : "2021-06-17",
    "exchange" : "bitpanda",
    "month" : "6",
    "year" : "2021"
  } ]
}
```

this is the instance of dataset

Comment: As this seems not to be an answer, consider updating you question instead. This would be the appropriate way to provide additional information asked for in comments. Thanks.

Comment: asking something for the first time, i guess i'm learning... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

After all my research on web, i've concluded that firebase realtime database api does not support nested queries with unknown paths. I should use another structure or filter data after fetching all the data(which is highly inefficient for large datasets). So i decided to try using firestore for news only without a news tag. I'll let you know if that way does the trick.

Comment: Your data structure seems to have a single dynamic level, which is what Firebase can query (with the code I included in my answer). Can you edit your question to include the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots), instead of a schematic representation? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Of course, i generated an instance of my data, i also tried to import it to firebase again and it works fine. So we can assume that it still represents the problem. I posted as answer.

Comment: Working code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69510142) on your data structure: https://jsbin.com/focaveq/3/edit?js,console